# How to add AWS inbound restriction for AWS instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, multiple-instances, inbound-security-rule

I have a application A in AWS which is dependent to another application B which is also in AWS ,but host B has many instances so it has many dynamic IPs how to add this IP in AWS inbound of Host A load balancer security group.Now for Example if i have 20 B host i should mention 20 ip in the host A load balancer security group is there any other ways?

Comment: I agree with @Tom! You will need to expose ELB as single point of access for your service B and point all requests from A to ELB instance which in turn can load balance your requests to different B service instances. And this way you can just add only 1 IP to your inbound restriction!

Comment: Could you please clarify your architecture? It appears that you have a Load Balancer in front of a single Amazon EC2 instance running Application A. You also seem to have multiple Amazon EC2 instances running Application B. Is there also a Load Balancer for Application B? Do you wish to grant access from all instances running Application B to access Application A? And would they access Application A directly, or would it be via the Application A Load Balancer? Feel free to edit your question to clarify your architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to put an [Elastic Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/what-is-load-balancing.html) in front of the B hosts, and have A make requests to the ELB. This allows A to not care about the IPs of the B hosts, and also helps spread load evenly across all the B hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Just put all of your application B instances in one security group, and add that security group to application A security group as the **custom source**.

[image]

So, it's mean all of application B instances with the same SG, can access your application A.

For more information about security groups, read the following documents on the AWS website:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#security-group-rules

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/security-group-rules-reference.html